# Open a pdf file using "Date modified" column - Console Application

Tags: c#, console-application

In my console application, I am generating some .pdf files and putting them in a specific folder. Each of these files have unique content with unique names. For example, a similar file names is "6cc32a23-321d-3v8ba181-aa4c38cd7e3a.pdf".

What I would like to do, is open these allow the user to open the pdf from within the console application. Of course they could navigate to the folder they are stored in each time, but I don't wan to do that.

Because the name of each file is unique, how can know which file to open? I had the thought of created a method that searches the folder based on the newest "Date modified". The method basically search the folder for the newest file and attempt to open it. Is that even possible? Any other suggestions would be helpful as well. Thanks!